# How to enforce synchronization between UISlider value and thumb position?

Tags: ios, uislider

I'm using a custom UISlider. I save the value after user input using `slider.value`. After a while, I need to restore the position of the slide to its saved value using `[slider setValue:savedValue]`.

But I noticed some discrepancies between the position at save time and the position after restoration.

After a while I found out that if the user moves the thumb very quickly, it goes further than the actual value (Some kind of momentum/inertia effect). How can I make sure that one value corresponds to one thumb position?

Comment: It may help if you could make a sample project available demonstrating the problem. Github is a great place to do that...

Comment: yes, I don't quite understand. they move the slider, but you want to override the user's movement?

Comment: The value recorded corresponds to the position of the thumb when the user stops touching the screen. However, the thumb continues to move (some inertia animation), so when you do a setValue (getValue) it moves back to the correct position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're catching `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to dictate 'finished', use `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` instead.

Failing that, you could key-value observe `value`, at each change cancelling future saves and, if `tracking` is false, scheduling a new for 0.5 seconds from now. E.g.

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(storeValue) object:nil];

if(!slider.tracking)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(storeValue) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

(or explicitly store whether a save is scheduled if you find any performance problem with that, I guess, but don't overcomplicate it unless you have to)

Comment: Thanks i think I can get inspiration from that, it's going in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Are you treating the value as an integer?

Because it (the UISlider object) stores a float, treating it as an integer can cause this behaviour..

Perhaps re-set it in the action where you process the change, I've found this necessary before once or twice..
Eg (this hooked up to the sliders (value changed) controlEvent....

```
-(IBAction) sliderMoved:(id)sender{
    
    UISlider *sld = (UISlider *)sender;
    CGFloat val = sld.value;
    val += 0.49; /// rounder...
    
    int result = (int) val;
    
    [sld setValue:(CGFLoat)result animated:YES];
    
    ///// etc process entry...
}
```

This kind of treatment turns the slider into a multi-position "switch", it snaps to whole number values..  You could be doing it with `fabsf(...)` function if you want to remain in the float territory too...